# Pagina exibindo erro

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Sou iniciante em spring com java e tenho o seguinte controller e jsp

Controller:

```
@Controller
//mapeamento do nome
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public class HelloController {

    //mapeamento do nome
    @RequestMapping("/controller")
    public ModelAndView hello() {

        //caminho da pagina .jsp
        return new ModelAndView("/hello/view", "message", "Bem-vindo ao spring");
    }
}
```

Pagina index.jsp

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="/hello/controller/"> Hello </a>
        <br />
        <a href="index.jsp"> Teste 1</a>
        <br />
    </body>
</html>
```

Pagina view.jsp

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Spring MVC</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <h2>${message }</h2>
    </body>
</html>
```

O problema é. Eu inicio normalmente a aplicação no tomcat. Acesso, "http://localhost:8080/projeto-exemplo/" e a pagina exibe corretamente. Porem, quando clico no link 'Hello', ele redireciona para o link "http://localhost:8080/hello/controller/" ... correto, POREM, exibe a mensagem de erro:

"HTTP Status 404 – Not Found Type Status Report

Message /hello/controller/

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists."

Mas, se eu coloco o link direto como "http://localhost:8080/projeto-exemplo/hello/controller/" A pagina é exibida corretamente.

No caso, como faço para corrigir o problema e exibir corretamente a pagina quando o link for redirecionado para "http://localhost:8080/hello/controller/" ?

Answer (score 2):

No link da sua JSP, você deve indicar o contexto da sua aplicação, conforme o exemplo abaixo:

```
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/hello/controller/"> Hello </a>
```

A expressão irá concatenar o contexto da sua aplicação ao link, direcionando ao endereço correto.

---

**UPDATE:** Referente à configuração da sua aplicação ficar diretamente na URL localhost:8080, você deve realizar o deploy diretamente para o context ROOT do servidor. Para isso você pode alterar o contexto de sua aplicação no arquivo `server.xml`, na tag `context` você irá ver o contexto de sua aplicação, desta forma é só alterar para `/`.

**No Eclipse:** Aba Server > Modules > Alterar o contexto da aplicação para `/`

**Importante:** Caso você altere o contexto de sua aplicação para usar diretamente a raiz, o `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` não será mais necessário conforme indicado acima.

---

**UPDATE**: Como depois de incluir o `${pageContext.request.contextPath}` você conseguiu chegar ao seu `@Controller`, caso ainda esteja apresentando 404 é devido ao direcionamento incorreto à sua página `view.jsp`

Tente da forma abaixo:

`return new ModelAndView("hello/view", // Trocando de /hello/view para hello/view
...`

Comment: Coloquei o comando que indicado, porem exibiu a mensagem de erro no jsp

Nesse caso, alterei meu caminho colocando um ponto. Ex:
    <a href="./hello/controller/"> Hello </a>

Porem, não sei se o que fiz é algo viável.

Comment: qual a URL exibida no browser agora?

Comment: agora exibe. Ex: 

"http://localhost:8080/projeto-exemplo/hello/controller/"

porem eu gostaria que exibisse http://localhost:8080/hello/controller/

Comment: A única forma de apresentar diretamente no localhost:8080 é realizando o deploy diretamente ao context ROOT do servidor. Outra questão, você verificou se ao debugar a requisição esta atingindo o controller?

Comment: Entendi. Sim, fiz o debug e o mesmo acessou o controller quando coloquei o "." no caminho. Sem o "." o mesmo ja nao consegue acessar o controller

Comment: Certo então, acessando o controller, caso ainda continue o 404 o problema está no redirecionamento para a `view.jsp`, tente seguir as instruções que atualizei na resposta, e também poste a estrutura de pastas do seu projeto e páginas.

Comment: Poste também o mapeamento das páginas  para sua pasta `views`

Comment: Editei a postagem e coloquei o conteudo do arquivo "ctx-web-application-context.xml" e "web.xml"

Answer (score 0):

Estou enviando a imagem com a estrutura de pasta do projeto

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Na aba Servers, acabei nao encontrando as opções que comentou

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Arquivo ctx-web-application-context.xml

```html
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

 <context:component-scan base-package="br.com.projetoexemplo.controller" />
 
 <mvc:annotation-driven />

 <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  
  <property name="prefix" value="/views/" />
  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
 </bean>
</beans>
```

Arquivo web.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

 <!-- DEFAULT PAGE -->
 <welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
 </welcome-file-list>

 <!-- SPRING MVC -->
 <servlet>
  <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/ctx-web-application-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```